# ¿Dónde puedo aprender sobre los archivos?

Tags: c++, c, archivo

Estoy interesado en aprender a manipular archivos en C++. He buscado información en Internet, pero lo único que encuentro son tutoriales que explican como manipular archivos desde algún lenguaje de programación sin explicar lo que está ocurriendo realmente.

Lo que me gustaría es aprender a fondo qué es un archivo y cómo los trata el sistema operativo, para entonces aprender a manipularlos con C o C++.

Tengo entendido por archivo un conjunto de bytes escritos en el disco duro, pero no sé qué delimita a un archivo de otro, si cuando se trabaja con archivos en RAM estos tienen la misma forma, y cómo los trata el sistema operativo. ¿Eso de marcar la escritura, lectura, etc. es algo necesario?, ¿Lo rige el sistema operativo, la placa base?, ¿Pueden dos procesos modificar un mismo archivo a la vez? ¿Dónde se almacenan el nombre y la extensión de un archivo? ¿Qué dice si un archivo es binario o ASCII? ...

¿Alguien sabe **qué debería hacer para aprender estas cosas** antes de ponerme a manipular archivos en C o C++? Gracias!

Comment: Estimado, es bien sabido por el [reglamento](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) que las preguntas basadas en opiniones no son bien recibidas en el foro, por favor modifica tu pregunta en incluye algún código para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Solo estoy preguntando por fuentes de información.

Comment: Fuentes de informacion se consideran basadas en opiniones (ya que cual es la respuesta correcta a una lista de tutoriales o paginas?). Un archivo es un conjunto de bytes grabados sobre un sistema operativo. Tal vez si explicaras que entendes vos, podriamos corregirte lo que pensas al respecto. Tene en cuenta que un archivo es nada misma, sin alguien que interprete el contenido. Creo que la pregunta se puede reformular un poco y la podemos trabajar.

Comment: He modificado la pregunta

Comment: AHHH ahora entiendo tu pregunta.. y aunque se puede poner una respuesta (que le va a faltar mucho), lo que estas preguntando se contesta con un manual (cualquiera) de ssistemas operativos... calcula que todo lo que preguntas es uno o mas capitulos sobre manejo de archivos en cualquiera de esos libros.

Comment: En este sitio podés usar `[c++][archivo]` en el cuadro de buscar que te aparece arriba para ver preguntas y respuestas que contengan esos dos temas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AVISO: Esta respuesta no es una respuesta completa, ya que el tema "archivos" dependa del sistema operativo donde se los maneje.

Vamos a bajar a conceptos basicos lo que preguntas.

Un archivo es un conjunto de bytes. Todo es un conjunto de bytes en la computadora. La cuestion es como entender ese conjunto de bytes.

En un sistema operativo, el que delimita a un archivo es el sistema operativo, que sabe desde que posición (bloque, particion o lo que sea del sistema de guardado) hasta que posición esta dicho árchivo.

Los archivos pueden estar partidos por todo el lugar (los bloques ni siquiera tienen que estar contiguos). El sistema operativo tiene una tabla que le dice cuales bloques tiene que leer (esto como generalidad) y cuando termina el árchivo.

Las marcas y todas las caracteristicas de los archivos las maneja el sistema operativo. Si es de solo lectura, lo maneja el SO. Eso no quiere decir que si sobrepasas el SO, no lo puedas escribir por ejemplo.

Todos los archivos son binarios. No hay otra forma de guardar un archivo que no sea con 0 y 1. Quien decide que contiene el archivo y como tratarlo, es el programa que lo lee. No importa la extension ni el nombre, el que decide como se debe tratar y que hay en cada posicion es quien lo tiene que usar.

El nombre se guarda en la tabla de archivos que mantiene el sistema operativo. Esa tabla tiene mucha mas informacion como permisos y otras cosas.

Y por ultimo, con los archivos se puede hacer todo lo que el sistema operativo te deje. O sea, si el sistema operativo permite que dos procesos lo usen al mismo tiempo, se puede.

Y mejor, estudiar todo esto de un manual de sistemas operativos.